# QGIS Zonal Statistics: Sum of Partial Area Larger Than Sum of Total Area

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I've been trying to use zonal statistics to get the proportion of a population in an area relative to the larger administrative district that the area falls under. My workflow is:

1. Run zonal statistics(sum) for red polygon.
2. Run zonal statistics(sum) for blue polygon.
3. Divide output of #2 by output of #1.

[image]

Strangely, the proportion comes out as greater than 100%, i.e. output of #2 is larger than #1. Why would this be happening and how can I solve this? I thought the issue was being caused by invalid geometries, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant subset of data you are looking at ? (this is in line with the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) Maybe just upload it somewhere. Then we can look at the same data and discuss further. Thank you!